# Fetching XML child values in c#

Tags: c#

I have some data i need to fetch from a xml file.

```
<book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
</book>
```

How would I fetch the year based of the category?

So it would be like

> writeline( FetchYearFromCategory("cooking") );

and it would output 2005

Hope you can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to Xml

```
// Load xml in the memory
var document = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile);

// Filter xml to find required data
var yearsOfCooking = 
    document.Descendants("book")
            .Where(book => book.Attribute("category").Value == "cooking")
            .Select(book => book.Element("year").Value);

// Print result
foreach (var year in yersOfCooking)
{
    Console.WriteLine(year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are looking for is called XPath. You can define which elements are going to match using a relatively easy syntax. W3Schools has a pretty good tutorial, if you are not already familiar with it. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) is the link.

The syntax to use it would be:

```
// This will fetch all "book" items in the root node
// that have the category = "cooking"
// and select their year node.
var strXPathExpression = "/book[@category='cooking']/year";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("YourXmlFile.xml");

var root = doc.DocumentElement;

var desiredNodes = root.SelectNodes(strXPathExpression).

foreach (var node in desiredNodes)
{
    // You have your year here
    var year = node.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx) to access XML Files in C#.NET

```
public int FetchYearFromCategory(string category){

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path_to_your_file");

XmlNodeList allBooks = doc.GetElementsByTagName("book");
foreach (XmlNode singleBookNode in allBooks)
{
    if(singleBookNode.Attributes["category"] != null && singleBookNode.Attributes["category"].Value.Equals(category))
    {
        XmlNodeList childNodes = singleBookNode.ChildNodes; 
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in childNodes)
        {
            if(childNode.Name.Equals("year"))
            {
                return Int32.Parse(childNode.InnerText);
            }           
        }       
    }   
}
return -1;}
```

I think the above should do you the job.